# Scroll view Moving to it's Original Position after Scrolling in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, ios6

In My Application i Added a UIScrollView on that scroll view i added two UITextField two UIButtons and one UIMapView and a UITablViewE using xib. now i added that scroll to my view controller using :

```
[self.view addSubView:scroll];
```

My problem is After scrolling it's Moving to it's original Position it is not showing the current page it is moving to top again. can any one please help me to overcome this problem.

Comment: There might be 2 issues. 
1. self.scroll.bounces = NO;
2. self.scroll.contentSize is not set with appropriate height.

Comment: Please put some more code . Its difficult to guess the problem from this much of code .

Comment: Please check scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(scrollView.size.width,(height For Scroll);

Answer (score 0):

store the scrollview's position in a `CGPoint` variable . You can get the position  by the delegate method every time it scrolls,

```
CGPoint scrollPosition;

    - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
       scrollPosition =  myScrollView.contentOffset
{
```

Then once you added it to the new View, manually scroll it to the previous position,

```
[myScrollView setContentOffset:scrollPosition];
```